# EVAL: undefined function NIL in Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, lambda-calculus

I'm trying to write a function named `calculate` that gets a list as an input, and calculates its value (works as a lambda calculus reducer).

Here's my code:

```
(defun substitue(x y z)
  (cond ((atom z) (cond ((eq z y) x)
                        (T z)))
        (T (cons (substitue x y (car z))
                 (substitue x y (cdr z))))))

(defun substitute-and-eval(x y z)
  (eval (substitue x y z)))

(defun calculate(l)
  (cond ((eq l nil) nil)
        ((atom l) (eval l))
        (T (substitute-and-eval (calculate (cdr l))
                                (calculate (car l))
                                l))))
```

but when I call the following line in Lisp, I get the error:

```
(calculate '((lambda (x) (+ x 2))
             (lambda (y) (y))
             ((lambda (z) (+ z 4)) 3)))
```

Error :

```
EVAL: undefined function NIL
```

So I traced the code and didn't find anywhere where I'm recursively calling `eval` on `nil`, so I couldn't find the problem. I also am not sure if my calculate function does what it should correctly. Since I'm a newbie in Lisp, I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we call `calculate` on `((lambda (z) (+ z 4)) 3)`, it then calls `calculate` on the `cdr` of above, which is `(3)`.

Then there is a call to `(substitute-and-eval nil 3 '(3))`. Which then tries to evaluate `(nil)`...

With a stepper the wrong call is easy to find, see `STEP`.